# How to change the link?

Tags: php

I have youtube link like http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bfp-T29m0BM

I want to do, when i put this link i want to print;

http://www.youtube.com/embed/Bfp-T29m0BM

How can I take just v value from input for example $link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bfp-T29m0BM';

$uri = parse_url($url);

parse_str($uri['query']);

echo 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/'. $v;
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$link = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bfp-T29m0BM";
$regex = preg_match("/\?v=([a-ZA-Z0-9-_]*)/", $link, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: This is probably the best solution, but there are many [string functions](http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) that OP could also read up on that could also be wrangled into a solution.

Comment: Yes sure @Sammitch , All Roads Lead to Rome, but i don't get what did you mean with "OP" it's shortcut or something like this ?

Comment: @MohammadAhmad OP == Original Poster

Answer (score 0):

Read up on using explode() in the php manual. Come back with some Code that you've tested.

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = parse_url($youtube_link);
parse_str($url['query'], $query);
echo "$url[scheme]://$url[host]/embed/$query[v]";
```